# Segmentation fault using relational operators in if condidtion

Tags: c, if-statement, segmentation-fault, operator-keyword, relational

The first if condition leads to a segmentation fault. I can't really comprehend why, since I use similar if clauses with relational operators elsewhere. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
int foo(char *str1,char **str2, char **str3)
{
  char *token1;
  char *token2;
  char *token = strtok(str1, "\"");
  int spaces = strcmp(token,"  ");
  int parenthesis = strcmp("{",token);
  if((token == NULL) || ((spaces != 0) && (parenthesis != 0))) 
  {
    printf("ERR.\n");
    return 0;
  } 
  token = strtok(NULL, "\"");
  if(token == NULL)
  {  
    printf("2ERR\n");
    return 0;
  }
  token1= strtok(NULL, "\"");
  if(token1 == NULL || strcmp(token1," -> ") != 0)
  {
    printf("3ERR\n");
    return 0;
  }
  token2 = strtok(NULL, "\"");
  return 1;
  }
```

Comment: Where is `parente` declared in this code snippet?

Comment: Where are `name_a` and `parente` defined? What do you pass as `str1` If it is a string literal or other const memory, `strtok()` will cause trouble when it tries to write `\'0'` into the string.

Comment: Are you sure that you even reach your `if` statement? Did you run it in debugger?

Comment: I put a printf right infront of the first if, and it was printed. and I only get a segmentation fault if one of the conditions would be false

Comment: @Gerhardh Str1 is allocated in dynamic memory.

Comment: Why don't you provide the code that you _really_ run? As you obviously created something different for SO, you might easily missed the important parts. BTW: You use token without any check for `NULL`.

Comment: Yes if've missed that too thanks :).

Comment: @Gerhardh And i've just tried to just put a 0 or 1 as a condition. And just using a 0 as a statement resulted in a segmentation fault too. So I'm a bit clueless. Its a larger program, and this is just a small piece, but i've only changed the variable names

Comment: In the if condition only automatic variables are evaluated. How should this ever cause a seg fault? Please show us the code that calls your function.

Answer (score 0):

The `strtok` will crash if you don't use `char[]`. You can get around it using `strcpy`.

```
char str[80];
strcpy(str, str1);
char *token = strtok(str, "\"");
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but your code will run without crashing after the small change.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int foo(char *str1,char **str2, char **str3)
{
    char *token1;
    char *token2;

    char str[80];
    strcpy(str, str1);
    char *token = strtok(str, "\"");
    int spaces = strcmp(token,"  ");
    int parenthesis = strcmp("{",token);
    if((token == NULL) || ((spaces != 0) && (parenthesis != 0)))
    {
        printf("ERR.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    token = strtok(NULL, "\"");
    if(token == NULL)
    {
        printf("2ERR\n");
        return 0;
    }
    token1= strtok(NULL, "\"");
    if(token1 == NULL || strcmp(token1," -> ") != 0)
    {
        printf("3ERR\n");
        return 0;
    }
    token2 = strtok(NULL, "\"");
    return 1;
}
int main() {

    char * c1, * c2, * c3;
    c1 = "foobaz";
    c2 = "bar";
    c3 = "baz";

    int i =  foo(c1, &c2, &c3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The statement "Function `strtok` will crash if you don't use `char[]`" is generally misleading, and not necessarily correct. Function `strtok` takes a pointer to a **non-constant** null-terminated array of characters. So for example, if you declare `const char str[5]`, you will get a segmentation fault (or more generally, undefined behavior) when calling `strtok(str,...)`. Since a string literal is constant by definition, this too cannot be passed as the first input argument of function `strtok`.

Comment: If a pointer is passed to `strtok` that points to memory from a dynamic allocation then we can assume that we do not have a problem with const memory.